# Undefined Control Sequence \TEXTBF

Tags: latex

I am getting the error shown in the attached photo, Please guide me to fix it. I am using overleaf site to write the paper.
[image]

Comment: unrelated to your question, but you should clean up your preamble. Don't load the same package multiple times -- and in particular not with different options. Also many of the options and commands are unnecessary, like the `pdftex` option to `graphicx` Cclean them up to only use the necessary ones.

Comment: I created a separate sample to show here. That's why my all packages are there. I am using all those packages in my full document. Though your answer to correct the case sensitivity worked for me. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: The additional packages are not the problem, doing unnecessary things like loading the SAME package multiple times, the `pdftex` option or the `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` are the things you should clean up.

Comment: Please [don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446). Questions with images of code are low quality anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX is case sensitive. Use

```
\textbf{...}
```

---

However to follow latex's principle to separate formatting and content, it would be better to not manually mess with the fonts like this. Instead your use-case seems to be better suited for a sectioning command like `\subsection{...}`, or whatever level you like.